# How to retrieve all KB articles?

Tags: apex, articles

I am trying to pull all the KB articles from the DB which meet my criteria:

1) visible in pkb

2) latest version

So I first pulled all the Ids without any filter:

```
List<Id> faqIds = new List<Id>();
for(FAQ__ka faq: [SELECT ID FROM FAQ__ka]) {
    faqIds.add(faq.id);
}
System.debug(loggingLevel.Debug, '*** faqIds size: ' + faqIds.size());
```

**//output: 692**

Then I used the 'faqIds' list as a condition:

```
faqArticles = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId,MasterVersionId FROM FAQ__kav 
               WHERE PublishStatus='Online' AND KnowledgeArticleId IN : faqIds AND IsVisibleInPkb=True AND IsLatestVersion=True];
System.debug(loggingLevel.Debug, '*** faqArticles: ' + faqArticles.size());
```

**//output: 1050**

Few questions:

1) Why am I getting so many records? I know that relationship between Article_Type__ka to Article_Type__ka**v** is 1-m, but I filter out all the older versions (by using IsLatestVersion=True)

2) How can it be resolved?